# fortran rewind state-rewind (variables)

Tags: fortran

I am studying now someone's Fortran code file:

```
REWIND NRTAP
REWIND NWTAP
REWIND 9
```

As far as I know, rewind statement sets point to initial point.
However, when variable name is after rewind state,
what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The thing following the rewind keyword designates the logical unit for the file to be rewound back to its initial point.

Previous in the execution of your program there may have been an OPEN statement that connected the relevant logical units.  NRTAP and NWTAP will be variables or constants that have been given an integer value elsewhere.